# Array Index Out of Exception in Java

Tags: java, arrays, function, loops

Could anyone help me to fix the error in my code? 
I've been trying and trying and can't find solution.. My brain is grilled now..

This is my code:

```
    public static String revio(String[] a){
        int N = a.length;
        String[] reverse = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
            reverse[i] = a[N-i-1];

        }
        return reverse[N];         
}
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] myArray = {"1", "2", "3"};  
        String arr = revio(myArray);
        System.out.println(arr);

    }
}
```

I know that I keep getting error because my array is in range of 0 to 2 and it tries to get access to index 3 which isn't in range of 0 to 2. Please give me a bit of advice!

Comment: Well.. How would you fix it? I use Jeliot to check errors and everything is perfectly fine there except the return statement.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the below, use `Arrays.toString()` or `StringBuilder`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static String revio(String[] a){
  int N = a.length;
  String reverse = new String[N];
  for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
  reverse[i] = a[N-i-1];  
  }
  return Arrays.toString(reverse); 
  }

 //using StringBuilder
  public static String revio(String[] a){
  int N = a.length;
  StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
  reverse.append(a[N-i-1]);  
  }
  return reverse.toString(); 
  }


public static void main (String[] args)
{
  String[] myArray = {"1", "2", "3"};  
  String arr = revio(myArray);
  System.out.println(arr);
}
```

Comment: Well.. It's an assignment and we are supposed to use "public static String revio(String[] a)
I already tried it the way you did :/. All the answers I keep getting about N-1 are wrong.. I tried it before as well..

Comment: I don't want to import anything. It wouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: @DerikDaro - See my updated answer using StringBuilder

Answer (score 6):

Your loop is ok but the line where you are returning from the method is accessing invalid index (3)

```
reverse[N];
```

change it to for e.g.

```
reverse[N - 1];
```

and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the element at `array.length`, because Java starts indexes at `0` (not `1`).

```
int N = a.length;
String[] reverse = new String[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
  reverse[i] = a[N-i-1];
}
return reverse[N - 1]; // <-- the last element.
```

Comment: This is not working. I get only the one value "1" in my outcome :/

Comment: When you return a `String` you will only get a single result. What do you expect? If you want the entire array you will need to change the return type, and return the array `reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

`return reverse[N];`  is the problem. It should be return `reverse[N-1];`

If you want to return the whole reversed array, you should use `return reesrve;`

Comment: I tried it before, but then I only one value from my array which is "1".